# Insert HTML verbatim from Freemarker node

Tags: freemarker

I have the following Freemarker code:

```
    <#macro table_container>
        <div class="table content">
            ${.node}
        </div>
    </#macro>
```

Now the node contains HTML (for a table) that I don't want parsed by Freemarker.  I just want it inserted as is.  Currently I get this error:

```
freemarker.template.TemplateModelException: Only elements with no child elements can be 
processed as text.
This element with name "table_container" has a child element named: table
```

How do I get Freemarker to insert this HTML verbatim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`${.node.@@markup}`, or if you are inside `#escape`, `<#noescape>${.node.@@markup}</#noescape>`. It has the minor ugliness though that it will add the required `xmlns` attributes for each such insertion.